# Android TextView doesn't display Sound Recording Copyright Symbol "℗"

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am working on an app that displays text and plays audio from an API. It also needs to display copyright information for that text and audio; this information is retrieved from the same API.

Many of the audio copyrights contain the "℗" symbol, also known as the Sound Recording Copyright Symbol:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_recording_copyright_symbol

However, when I take the text retrieved from the API and put it in a TextView, the "℗" symbol doesn't show up. The normal copyright symbol (©) shows just fine.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Assuming that the "text retrieved from the API" is using `&#8471;` in HTML or Unicode U+2117, perhaps the font that you are using does not have that symbol.

Comment: That certainly seems like the most likely explanation. Of course, I'm not using any special font, so that means that Android's built-in font doesn't have it. Which means I'd have to bundle a custom font in my app just to display this one character. Hardly seems worth it.

Comment: I have Droid Sans and Droid Sans Mono installed as desktop fonts on my Ubuntu machine, and U+2117 showed up in the character map for them. I have not checked Roboto, as I don't have that installed. Now that I think about it, though, usually a missing Unicode glyph results in a small rectangle placeholder, rather than nothing. Are you sure that this character is coming through as expected from your API? Is this HTML that you are decoding, or is it a Unicode string that you are getting, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I used the debugger to check the string being returned by the API, and the character is definitely there. It's not HTML; just a straightforward Unicode string. My current working solution is to use String.replace() to replace the character with "(P)". This is less than ideal, but at least it displays.

Comment: On the emulator (2.3.3) I do see the rectangle placeholder but not on my phone (4.4.2) just a blank. The closest character I found that seemed to display okay for both is `U+24DF` or `&#9439;` in HTML. It's a small letter P in a circle. The capital P one would only display as a P on my phone..

Comment: This is funny. I just opened this post in the Stack Overflow Android app, and I noticed that the character in question doesn't display here either. I'm on 4.4.2, and I get a blank space as well. I also opened the Wikipedia link in the Wikipedia app, and I see the same thing. So this is definitely an Android issue. Probably the font doesn't include that character. What an odd omission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try thus ways. such as

first create string value in res/values/string.xml . for example

```
<string name="copyright">\u2117 2011 copyright</string>
```

then get this from your activity class thus way. such as

```
 TextView tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.copyright));
```

Comment: Since it's XML, not JSON, `&#x2117;` has higher chance of working.